# Getting contents of a plist

Tags: objective-c, plist, nsdictionary

How can I get the content of this plist?

I am a little confused on the different elements and how to access them.

[image]

How does one access these dictionaries, and dictionaries in dictionaries?

What if I want to copy this data first, would it increase performance by a lot, rather than always reading from the plist?

How can I get all of this data into my app, by going through the structure levels?

Thank you

Answer (score 10):

The easiest way to read a property list is by using a convenience method on `NSDictionary` *(Or `NSArray` if your root element is an array)* like so:

```
NSString* filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"FileName" 
                                                     ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary* plist = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

From there on the plist file is just a normal dictionary. Use `objectForKey:`, etc to get to the values. For faster access to deep child nodes you can use `valueForKeyPath:` like this for example:

```
NSString* name = [plist valueForKeyPath:@"mainDictionary.name"];
```

For more complex operations on plist files you should use `NSPropertyListSerialization` that have several class methods for more more fine grained access to reading and writing property list files.

Answer (score 1):

```
    use this :
    NSDictionary *dic1 = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentofFile:yourFilePathhere];

// return main dictionary
    NSDictionary *dic2 = [dic1 objectForKey:mainDictionary];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the [NSPropertyListSerialization class](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPropertyListSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html), which makes parsing plists relatively straightforward.

Here's a bit of sample code: http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/tag/nspropertylistserialization

Answer (score 0):

## Swift Code

```
let filePath:String = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("infoList_English", ofType: "plist")!
let postDictionary : NSDictionary = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: filePath)!
print(postDictionary)
```